# ClassCastException w/ @TestFor in Grails 2.4.4

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException` when I use the `@TestFor` annotation in a Spock test in Grails 2.4.4.

Here's my code:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SnsService)
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SnsServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def "test something"() {
        expect:
        service.name == "bacon"
    }

}
```

Here's the error message:

```
| Running 2 unit tests... 1 of 2
| Failure:  test something(com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.SnsServiceSpec)
|  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.SnsService
        at com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.SnsServiceSpec.test something(SnsServiceSpec.groovy:16)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests FAILED  - view reports in /Users/terskine/git/myphotoid-api/target/test-reports
```

---

However, if I just declare the service, everything works:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(SnsService)
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SnsServiceSpec extends Specification {

    SnsService service = new SnsService()

    def "test something"() {
        expect:
        service.name == "bacon"
    }

}
```

Then, I get:

```
grails> test-app -unit SnsService
| Completed 1 unit test, 0 failed in 0m 0s
| Tests PASSED - view reports in /Users/terskine/git/myphotoid-api/target/test-reports
```

I have tons of unit tests in the same project that use the `@TestFor` annotation but do not need to declare the component explicitly.

What am I missing?  I'm sorry in advance if it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding the GrailsUnitTestMixin? Is that even necessary?

Comment: `grails create-unit-test` added it.  I tried removing it and it didn't make any difference.